# I want to create a query with CDbCriteria with joins

Tags: join, criteria, yii

`SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 m WHERE a.colid=1 and m.colid=1 order by a.date desc`

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria is a great read, there are examples at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your table structure is like below

```
        Table1
        ==========================
        colid | col2 | col3 | col4


        Table2
        ==========================
        colid | col2 | col3 | col4
```

**Relationship is Important**

In Yii framework ActiveRecords concept is performing huge role in database operations. An AR Class refers a database table. To perform relational queries you should define the relations ship between the tables. You can do this using **relations()** method in your models. Kindly observe below syntax.

If Table1 has more relational entities in Table2 than the relations ship should be as

```
 class Table1 extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function relations()
     {
          return array(
              'table2' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Table2', 'colid'),
          );
     }
 }
```

Here, Table2 also has relationship with Table1. ie,

```
 class Table2 extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function relations()
     {
          return array(
              'table1' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Table1', 'colid'),
          );
     }
 }
```

If you have these instructions in your program now you are eligeble to perform relational queries.

**Using CDbCriteria**

```
    $cri = new CDbCriteria();
    $cri->join = 'JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.colid = 1 and t2.colid = 1';
    $cri->order = 'col3 DESC'; //In your case date fields

    $RS = Table1::model()->findAll($cri);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($RS);
    echo "</pre>";

    //to echo col2 info of table1
    echo $RS[0]->col2;

    //to echo col1 info of table2
    echo $RS[0]->table2[0]->col2;
```

You can do the same with one line

```
     $info = Table1::model()->findByPk(1);
     echo ($info->table2[0]->col2);
```

I hope it may help you to compute the instructions in your program.

Comment: If use `'table2' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Table2', 'colid', 'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),` There is no more need using CDbCriteria for joining.